# Get List of all classes affecting a element including derived classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the list of all stylesheet rules that is affecting the current element.
Something like what firebug or native inspect element does.

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: Hey Sergio, the link which u gave lists all the css styles.. I am looking for Matched CSS Rules which are affecting the current style

Comment: Hey @Floradu88 , as for what I have tried so far... I think I was searching for the wrong thing.. I should have been searching for Matched CSS Rules ... I found this library http://www.brothercake.com/site/resources/scripts/cssutilities/ that would work for perfectly in my scenario.. <I still haven't integrated it yet, but once I do I'll post the answer here>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

brothercake.com/site/resources/scripts/cssutilities